# How do I get the page width in a css.

Tags: javascript, css, page-size

How do I get the page width in a css. Getting window width/height is easy. eg: Height: 100% sets the height to 100% of the window height. I want to set it to 100% of the page size. because if we zoom when using window size, max size it takes is of the window.

Comment: You'll have to explain a little bit more. It sounds like you're using a mobile?

Comment: I'm not sure what the difference between window and page is, they seem like the same thing to me. Also to clarify, setting width or height to 100% does not fill the window or page, it fills the width of the parent container. The parent container could be the window/document/page (whatever you are calling it) or it could also be another <div> (or other HTML element).

Answer (score 0):

**jquery** can give you a solution as follows:

```
$(window).height();   // returns height of browser viewport
$(document).height(); // returns height of HTML document
```

so you can use `$(document).height();`

Comment: I want to use it in css. Can jQuery be used in css??

Comment: var docHeight = $(document).height(); will get the height of the document then $('your_div').height(docHeight); wil give that height to your div.

Comment: that works fine. But I want to set the Height in the .CSS file

Comment: I don't think if there is a way to get the height of document with css, you can check this fiddle link to get it with jquery http://jsfiddle.net/Mohinder/svfhP/